# USB stopped working after computer woke from sleep

Tags: windows-7, usb, sleep

After my computer woke up from sleeping, my three USB ports stopped working.  Windows 7 wouldn't recognize them anymore.  On the rare occasion that they show up in Device Manager, it shows a yellow exclamation symbol next to that USB port.  I've followed every troubleshooting step [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/953367), but to no avail.

I've looked at other questions and websites but there's nothing that works, or at least nothing new to try.  Rebooting multiple times hasn't done anything.  This is also a new (as in, not previously used) laptop (Dell Latitude E7450), so I don't believe it's the drivers.

Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: Verify all updated BIOS, drivers and Windows Updates are installed. Sometimes these updates can resolve issues. Is it still under warranty?

Comment: @CharlieRB It's still under warranty, since it's my work laptop and I only got it last month.  All Windows Updates are installed.

Comment: I would suggest not messing with it. You might inadvertently void the warranty if you mess with too much. Call support and use the warranty.

Comment: @CharlieRB has a good point, but I believe that warranty is covering only hardware meaning you shouldn't be opening up the laptop. Have you tried to run [Windows 7 troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshooting-windows#troubleshooting-windows=windows-7)?